# Constructor taking Base& is not called

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I'm working on a simple program for Boolean algebra, but the double negation does not work as expected.

I have the following classes:

Operator:

```
#ifndef OPERATOR_H
#define OPERATOR_H

class Operator {
public:
    virtual int getArity(void) const = 0;
    virtual bool calc(void) const = 0;
};

#endif // OPERATOR_H
```

False:

```
#ifndef FALSE_H
#define FALSE_H

#include "operator.h"

class False : public Operator {
public:
    int getArity() const {
        return 0;
    }

    bool calc(void) const {
        return false;
    }
};

#endif // FALSE_H
```

Not:

```
#ifndef NOT_H
#define NOT_H

#include "operator.h"

class Not : public Operator {
public:
    Not(Operator& child) : m_child(child) {
        std::cout << "not constructor called" << std::endl;
    }

    int getArity(void) const {
        return 1;
    }

    bool calc(void) const {
        return !m_child.calc();
    }

private:
    Operator& m_child;
};

#endif // NOT_H
```

My main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "operator.h"
#include "not.h"
#include "false.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    False f;
    Not n = Not(f);
    Not d = Not(n);

    cout << "n.calc(): " << n.calc() <<endl;
    cout << "d.calc(): " << d.calc() <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since d = Not(Not(False())) I expect it to be false.

The output is:

```
not constructor called
n.calc(): 1
d.calc(): 1 <== should be 0
```

Why is the constructor of the class `Not` not called with an object of type `Not` as child?

Comment: The best way I've found to figure out what happens in cases like this is to implement *every* constructor and add some debug statements, explicitly logging every constructor called.  It can be *very* informative.

Comment: Aside:  I would highlight this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative  and beg you to reconsider what you're doing.    (And at last checking, false is not an operator, but a binary value)

Comment: note that `T x = T(a);` is defined as being the same as `T x(a);`, since C++17.

Comment: @UKMonkey "false" is usually the name of a boolean value, but it is also the name of a nullary operator (meaning it doesn't take any argument) that returns that boolean value.

Comment: The only major design "flaw" I see here is that you should probably use templates instead of inheritance. But that has nothing to do with the error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Not d = Not(n);` invokes the copy constructor of `Not`, because the argument is also of type `Not`. The copy constructor's signature matches better and it's therefore selected.

Comment: More detail: `Not(Operator& child)` is not a copy-constructor, despite the fact that it *can* be called with an argument of the same type.  The implicitly-defined copy-constructor also exists.

Comment: As a possible solution, you could take Operator* child, or pass the value with static_const<Operator&>. To avoid the silent copy, you can delete the copy-constructor and use uniform initialization syntax.